# Nonlinear ODE of the second order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is there a way to solve analytically following ODE with arbitrary smoothness $f(x)$
$$y''(x)y(x) = f(x)$$
I tried to get series solution in the form $y(x) = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{ + \infty } {{y_k}{x^k}} $, it follows to
$$\sum\limits_{k = 2}^{ + \infty } {{x^{k - 2}}\sum\limits_{j = 2}^k {j(j - 1){y_j}{y_{k - j}}} }  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{ + \infty } {{f_k}{x^k}} $$
and we can find reccurence
$${y_{k + 2}} = \frac{{{f_k} - \sum\limits_{j = 0}^{k - 1} {(j + 1)(j + 2){y_{j + 2}}{y_{k - j}}} }}{{{y_0}(k + 1)(k + 2)}}$$
where ${y_0},{y_1}$ are free parameters. But i can't find general form of ${y_k}$ from this.

Comment: How do you get your second equation from the first?  The derivative of $(y'(x)-2) y(x)$ is not $y''(x) y(x)$.

Comment: Even for something as simple as $F(x) = x^2+1$, I don't think there is a closed-form solution.  Of course there are series solutions.

Comment: Yeah, it's stupid mistake ($2y'$ instead of $y{'^2}$), I'll correct the start post.
I tried series solution, using
$$\sum\limits_{k = 2}^{ + \infty } {{x^{k - 2}}\sum\limits_{j = 2}^k {j(j - 1){y_j}{y_{k - j}}} }  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{ + \infty } {{f_k}{x^k}} $$
and get recurrence
$${y_{k + 2}} = \frac{{{f_k} - \sum\limits_{j = 0}^{k - 1} {(j + 1)(j + 2){y_{j + 2}}{y_{k - j}}} }}{{{y_0}(k + 1)(k + 2)}}$$
but it's not easy to find general form of ${y_k}$